# How to circumvent `take_while` skipping values?

Tags: rust

In trying to chain [`std::iter::Iterator::take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) calls together I'm losing the last values of each call.

Is there a way to chain calls together like this without skipping values?

Code [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62cbd204d22fb0388c31d31a73f9046f):

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Point {
    value: u8,
    xe: u8,
    xs: u8,
    y: u8,
}

impl fmt::Debug for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // All values following 5s within its x distance, partitioned by whether it is above or below.

    // Sorted by xs (x start) (xe = x end)
    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let vec:Vec<Point> = vec![
        Point { value: 4, xe: 1, xs: 1, y: 2 }, // 4
        Point { value: 3, xe: 3, xs: 2, y: 3 }, // 3
        Point { value: 5, xe: 7, xs: 4, y: 6 }, // ---- 5 -----
        Point { value: 3, xe: 5, xs: 5, y: 4 }, // 3
        Point { value: 6, xe: 6, xs: 6, y: 8 }, // 6
        Point { value: 2, xe: 8, xs: 8, y: 3 }, // 2
        Point { value: 8, xe: 10, xs: 9, y: 2 }, // 8
        Point { value: 5, xe: 15, xs: 10, y: 7 }, // ---- 5 -----
        Point { value: 2, xe: 12, xs: 11, y: 10 }, // 2
        Point { value: 7, xe: 13, xs: 13, y: 9 }, // 7
        Point { value: 4, xe: 14, xs: 14, y: 2 } // 4
    ];

    let mut iter = vec.iter();
    loop {
        let c: Vec<_> = iter
            .by_ref()
            .take_while(|x| x.value != 5)
            .cloned()
            .collect();

        println!("c: {:.?}", c);

        if let Some(var) = iter.next() {
            println!("var: {:.?}", var);

            let (a, b): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = iter
                .by_ref()
                .take_while(|x| x.xe < var.xe)
                .partition(|x| x.y > var.y);

            println!("a: {:.?}", a);
            println!("b: {:.?}", b);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c: [4, 3]
var: 3
a: []
b: []
c: [2, 8]
var: 2
a: []
b: []
c: [4]
```

It should output:

```
c: [4, 3]
var: 5 
a: [3]
b: [6] 
c: [2, 8]
var: 5
a: [2, 7]
b: [4]
```

Using `take_while` with [`std::iter::Iterator::partition`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.partition) seemed a good way to make the code for this relatively clean.

In context the `c`, `a` and `b` values would be passed to functions whose results would be appended to a return value.

Comment: You can use the [`take_while_ref`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.take_while_ref) method from the `itertools` crate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`next_if()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html#method.next_if) and [`from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html):

```rust
use std::iter::from_fn;

// ...

let mut iter = vec.iter().peekable();

// ...

let c: Vec<_> = from_fn(|| iter.next_if(|x| x.value != 5))
                    .cloned()
                    .collect();

// ...

let (a, b): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = from_fn(|| iter.next_if(|x| x.xe < var.xe))
                                   .partition(|x| x.y > var.y);
```

---

Using [`peeking_take_while()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.peeking_take_while) (better) or [`take_while_ref()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.take_while_ref) from itertools, just replace the function.

Comment: Not part of the main question but another issue I encountered right after, if within the the closure for `peeking_take_while()` the condition instead depends upon a number of following values (e.g. the next value must be 3 and the 2nd next must be 6). Do you have recommendations for handling that? (the best I can currently get it is using `.enumerate()` to do `check(*i,&vec)` (see https://pastebin.com/HKTRK6s1), but I think perhaps `check(iter.clone().take(2))` might be better)

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light Based a few information you give I would said `from_fn(|| check(&mut iter))` is probably the best. if your always expect the same number of value consider https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows